# Supabase policy results in empty array after executing RPC function

Tags: postgresql, policy, supabase, row-level-security

In order to activate RLS for my project, I am using the following Supabase policy for my table "quotations":

`(customername = ((auth.jwt() -> 'app_metadata'::text) ->> 'customername'::text))`

the app_metadata.customername is filled with the correct value string and has the data type text. Other rpc functions work well with this policy as well.

the rpc function takes in an object as argument:

```
{
  p_customername: 'testCompany',
  p_pod: 'Santos [BRSSZ]',
  p_zipcodes: null,
  p_incoterm: 'exw',
  p_typ: 'Export',
  p_modus: 'FCL',
  p_transportmode: 'Oceanfreight',
  p_carrier: null,
  p_startrow: 0,
  p_endrow: 50
}
```

```
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT *
        FROM quotations
        WHERE (quotations.customername = p_customername)
        AND (p_pod is null or quotations.pod = p_pod)
        AND (p_zipcodes is null or quotations.transportplace = p_zipcodes)
        AND (p_incoterm is null or quotations.incoterm = p_incoterm)
        AND (p_typ is null or quotations.typ = p_typ)
        AND (p_modus is null or quotations.modus = p_modus)
        AND (p_transportmode is null or quotations.transportmode = p_transportmode)
        AND (p_carrier is null or quotations.carrier = p_carrier)
        ORDER BY id DESC
        OFFSET p_startrow
        LIMIT p_endrow - p_startrow + 1;
END;
```

when I turn of RLS, the rpc function works fine.
if I turn it on, there is no error, but the result is simply an empty array.

I really don't get it. Can you kindly help out?
Thank you!

Comment: I assume when you make the call the `p_customername` and the `customername` in the JWT are the same?